# How can I get ElementType of an Array for building an Extension?

Tags: swift

I want make a custom Enumerated function, for that reason I need to know the type of value in my array, how can I read that information, here what I tried but need correction:

```
extension Array {
    
    typealias EnumeratedType<T> = [(index: Int, item: T)]                     // T: is the type of Elements of Array!
    
    func customEnumerated() -> EnumeratedType<ElementType> {
        
        var enumeratedTypeArray: EnumeratedType<ElementType> = EnumeratedType()
        
        self.sorted().forEach { item in
            
            enumeratedTypeArray.append((index: enumeratedTypeArray.count, item: item))
            
        }
        
        return enumeratedTypeArray
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: So, your `customEnumerated` function just does `Array(someArray.sorted().enumerated())`?

Comment: It is just for learning, maybe I add more functions as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array), we can see that `Array` is declared as:

```
struct Array<Element>
```

So the element type is called `Element`. You can declare your method like this:

```
extension Array where Element : Comparable {
    // note that this doesn't need to be generic, because the type alias is in the scope of the array
    typealias EnumeratedType = [(offset: Int, element: Element)]
    func customEnumerated() -> EnumeratedType {
        // you can simplify the forEach call to this
        .init(sorted().enumerated())
    }
}
```

Note that the constraint `Element : Comparable` is required, as that makes the parameterless overload of `sorted` available.

I would suggest that you declare the extension on the most general type possible, so that your method is available to as many types as possible, and return an `EnumeratedSequence` (same as what `enumerated` returns) instead. This way you don't need your own `EnumeratedType` type alias.

```
// It just so happens that the element type of a Sequence is also called "Element"
// See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2908099-element 
extension Sequence where Element : Comparable {
    func customEnumerated() -> EnumeratedSequence<[Element]> {
        sorted().enumerated()
    }
}
```

Comment: I just wanted to know, if I want use my own way of EnumeratedType I must make **enumeratedTypeArray** variable inside my function, can we return the function without using that variable? I am thinking to using map, is it right way of thinking?

Comment: @swiftPunk Yes, something like `sorted().enumerated().map { (index: $0.offset, item: $0.element) }`, but mapping just to change the tuple labels is a bit silly IMO. I would just change the tuple labels of `EnumeratedType` to `(offset: Int, element: Element)` like I did in the first code snippet instead.

Comment: Swift is a type inferred language. `Array<(offset: Int, element: Element)>` is redundant. Just  `.init(sorted().enumerated())`

Comment: @LeoDabus I tried it and it will actually incorrectly infer it as `Array<Element>`, for some reason, which is why I explicitly specified the type.

Comment: @Sweeper It works for me. It will always infer the returning type. Note also that enumerate on a sequence would allow OP to enumerate a slice as well and the offset would not work as an index. Not all collections indices are zero based

Comment: @LeoDabus Ah, I was trying `Array(sorted().enumerated())`. Apparently type inference works differently if you use the name of the type but omit type parameters, vs if you use `.init`? That's very weird...

Comment: @Sweeper yes if you specify `[Element]` or `Array`
 as the return type is exactly the same. You can also return `Self`

Answer (score -1):

As you can see in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array), the name of `Array`’s sole generic type parameter is `Element`.

Comment: You don't have to know it directly, you just need to know how to look it up when you need it